# Create a list from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary, inject

How do I convert this array:

```
@list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Into a new array like this with the keys prepended:

```
@new_list = ["1. one", "2. two", "3. three", "4. four"]
```

using `each` and `inject` in Ruby?

Comment: Why the requirement that we have to use inject? I could see `inject` or `each`, but not both. Is this homework?

Comment: It's also quite useful, especially for you, to answer [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 8):

Collect/map is the more natural approach here.

```
@new_list = @list.map.with_index {|item, index| "#{index+1}. #{item}"}
```

as of ruby 1.9 you can chain enumerators like this

Comment: In 1.9.2 (maybe all 1.9) you can also do `@list.collect.with_index {...}`, it's a bit cleaner to read :)

Comment: I agree. Also, FWIW, it's probably best to use the `map` alias, for three reasons: it's less typing, it is much more commonly used, and it matches the map/reduce terminology found in other languages.